# Sitecore Inheriting an Item from Branches (Inheriting complete structure)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In the Sitecore 7.0, Content Editor, is it possible to set the base template of an item lets say 'Bank' to a Branch Item (By Branch item I mean an item created in `/sitecore/templates/Branches/`) Lets say the Branch item is `Company` with 2 Folders in it `Address` and `Contacts` .

So that when an item is created from Template "`Bank`" the 2 folders "Address" and "Contacts" also get created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is no,

But, you may define a branch definition outside the `/sitecore/templates/Branches/` location. A Branche is just a item from Template `/sitecore/templates/System/Branches/Branch` if its helps you with the structure.

An other options to create the folders automatically is with a item:added event.

And if you want to share the structure with other branches you can try to clone the branch, but than you create also clones, I never used that in this way, no idea if it works correctly.